# Amazon Aws EC2 - Bitnami - wordpress configuration - extremely slow loading assets

Tags: wordpress, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I am trying to test out the feasibility of moving my website from godaddy to AWS.

I used a wordpress migrate plugin which seems to have moved the complete site and at least peripherally appears to be moved properly.
However, when I try to access the site, it is extremely slow. Upon using developer tools, I can tell that some of the css and jpg images are sort of acting as blocking threads. 
However, I cannot tell why this is the case. The site loads in less than 3 seconds in godaddy, however, it takes over a minute to load it fully on AWS and there are at least a few requests that timeout. Waterfall view on chrome developer tools show a lot of waiting on multiple requests and I cannot seem to figure out what or why these requests are sort of waiting forever and timing out.

Any guidance is appreciated.

I have pointed the current instance to www. blind beliefs .com

I cannot seem to figure out if it is an issue with the bitnami wordpress AMI or if I am doing something wrong. May be I should go the traditional route of spinning up EC2 instance , run a server on it, connect it to a db and then install wordpress on my server. I just felt the AMI available took care of all of that tailoring without me having to manually doing it.
However, it is difficult to debug though as to why certain assets get blocked/are extremely slow and timeout without loading.
Thank you.
Some more details:

The domain is still at godaddy and I have not moved it to AWS yet, not sure if that is sort of having an impact. 
I still feel it has to do with the AMI though - cannot prove it.

Comment: Your primary AWS instance may not be the problem.  You're loading two `.jpg` files from a different IP than your www site - why is that?  That site (54.234.148.234) is an AWS IP but isn't responding with anything.  Why do you have a hard coded IP?

Comment: i think the migrating plugin may have made those changes. I have just fixed those. Thank you for pointing those out.

Comment: There is still a Javascript file coming from that location.  Because the Javascript files are referenced at the top of your HTML it could still block.  Use the tools from the browser - you'll see that it gets a 504 or other error.  Fix those first.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue sounds like you have a free memory problem. You did not go into details on the instance size, if MySQL is installed on the instance, etc.

This article will show you how to determine memory usage on your instance. When free memory is low OR you start using SWAP space, your machine will become very slow. Your goal should be 0 bytes used in SWAP space and at least 25% free memory during normal operations.

Other factors to check is percent CPU utilization and free disk space on your file systems.

[Linux Memory Check Commands](https://www.linux.com/blog/5-commands-check-memory-usage-linux)

If you have a free memory problem, increase the instance size. If you have a CPU usage problem, either change the instance size or switch to another instance type. If you have a free disk space problem, create a new instance with a larger EBS volume OR move your website, etc to a new EBS volume sized correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for a quick response. I had posted the same question on the Amazon forums and did not hear or received a comment in the last 4-5 days. I really appreciate you trying to help out. 

.

You are correct in that the mysql instance is installed on the instance. I had the instance as t2.micros early on - but then I changed it to t2.large and still see the issue. There are certain assets/css/js files that take forever to load.

Comment: You should not be having a problem with T2.large. What were the results of the memory tests?

Comment: Hi Bitnami Engineer here. As @JohnHanley mentioned, you should not have problems with a t2.large instance. Using a t2.micro instance, you might run into issues depending on the content and the number of users of your site. In your case, I'd check if the bitnami configuration for Apache and MySQL is working fine or not. You will see some links inside the configuration folders of Apache (apache2/conf/bitnami) and the MySQL one (mysql/bitnami). To which file are the httpd.conf and my.cnf files linked to?